# Underscore.js - Check if Object Array contains value

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have the following Object and I want to check if Type.ID contains value 6508 :

```
 {
   "item": {
      "Feature": [
         {
            "ID": 85408,
            "Status": {
                "ID": 65,
             },
             "Type": {
                 "ID": 6508,
                  "Volume": null
              },
              "Manufacturer": null
          },
          {
             "ID": 85409,
             "Status": {
                 "ID": 65,
              },
              "Type": {
                  "ID": 6509,
                   "Volume": null
              },
              "Manufacturer": null
          }
       ],
       "Errors": {
           "Result": 0,
           "Message": ""
        },
       "RecordCount": 2
      }
 }
```

I can muster the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.item.Feature.length; i++) {
     if (data.item.Feature[i].Type.ID == 6508)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

How can I use underscore.js to do the same? The following doesn't work?

```
_.contains(data.item.Feature.Type.ID, 6508)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need underscore for this; example in plain JS.

```
data.item.Feature.some(function(x) { return x.Type.ID === 6508 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Using @FakeRainBrigand JS code I've manged to achieve the same using underscore by doing the following:

```
_.some(data.item.Feature, function(f) {
       return f.Type.ID == 6508;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion bro, if in case you want whole object (Inside 'Feature' List) not just the Boolean according to your search criteria, you can go this way as mentioned below.

```
var val = _.findWhere(data.item.Feature, {'Type': _.findWhere(_.pluck(data.item.Feature, 'Type'), {ID: 6509})});
```

This will return:

```
{
 "ID":85409,
 "Status":{
 "ID":65
},
 "Type":{
    "ID":6509,
    "Volume":null
    },
 "Manufacturer":null
}
```